# how to ignore a field data while comparing 2 files in python

Tags: python

Input files are as below with fields schema `asMode|Date|Count|timestamp|status|insertTimeStamp`

```
test1.txt:
HR|06/08/2016|3000|Thu Jun 09 2016|Complete|20160627020300
HR|06/08/2016|2000|Thu Jun 09 2016|Complete|20160627020400
HR|06/08/2016|1000|Thu Jun 09 2016|Complete|20160627020500
test2.txt:
HR|06/08/2016|3010|Thu Jun 09 2016|Complete|20160627070300
HR|06/08/2016|2000|Fri Jun 09 2016|Complete|20160627080300
HR|06/08/2016|1500|Thu Jun 09 2016|Complete|20160627090300
```

Now my requirement is to compare the difference lines between both the files, but it should ignore `insertTimeStamp` field (last column data) while comparing.

I tried below code. It's working fine, but its comparing line by line. Could someone please suggest me how can my code skip the `insertTimeStamp` field while comparison?

Thanks in advance for helping me.

```
import difflib
import sys

with open('/tmp/test1.txt', 'r') as hosts0:
    with open('/tmp/test2.txt', 'r') as hosts1:
        diff = difflib.unified_diff(
            hosts0.readlines(),
            hosts1.readlines(),
            fromfile='hosts0',
            tofile='hosts1',
            n=0,
        )
        for line in diff:
            for prefix in ('---', '+++', '@@'):
                if line.startswith(prefix):
                    break
            else:
                sys.stdout.write(line[1:])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could potentially just slice off the last element in each line before passing them into the diff function

```
diff = difflib.unified_diff(
    ['|'.join(x.split('|')[:-1]) for x in hosts0.readlines()],
    ['|'.join(x.split('|')[:-1]) for x in hosts1.readlines()],
    fromfile='hosts0',
    tofile='hosts1',
    n=0,
)
```

Line-by-line comparison w/o using difflib:

```
with open('/tmp/test1.txt', 'r') as fh:
    hosts1 = fh.readlines()
with open('/tmp/test2.txt', 'r') as fh:
    hosts2 = fh.readlines()  

for h1, h2 in zip(hosts1, hosts2):
    if h1.split('|')[:-1] != h2.split('|')[:-1]:
        print 'Lines are not the same!'
```

Comment: Thanks Its giving o/p as below:                        HR|06/08/2016|3000|Thu Jun 09 2016|Complete
HR|06/08/2016|2000|Thu Jun 09 2016|Complete
HR|06/08/2016|1000|Thu Jun 09 2016|Complete
HR|06/08/2016|3010|Thu Jun 09 2016|Complete
HR|06/08/2016|2000|Fri Jun 09 2016|Complete
HR|06/08/2016|1500|Thu Jun 09 2016|Complete   But my expected o/p is : HR|06/08/2016|3000|Thu Jun 09 2016|Complete|20160627020300
HR|06/08/2016|3010|Thu Jun 09 2016|Complete|20160627070300
HR|06/08/2016|1000|Thu Jun 09 2016|Complete|20160627020500
HR|06/08/2016|1500|Thu Jun 09 2016|Complete|20160627090300.

Comment: The code you gave is just trimming the last field (insertTimeStamp) in o/p. But my requirement is to compares line 1 in file1 with line 1 in file2 and line 2 in file 1 with line 2 in file 2 and so on..but during comparison it should just ignore last field(insertTimeStamp). For ex. record 2 in both the files can be exempted from o/p though last field(insertTimeStamp) differs.

Comment: So you want to compare two files line-by-line. Gotcha.  Do you need the output from difflib?  If you only want to compare two files line-by-line and don't need to see the diff, that will simplify the answer

Comment: Thanks for you help sir. Now the code is working fine